# ItemAdding never fired

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom content type with two event handler attached : ItemAdded and ItemAdding.
The first one (ItemAdded) is fired without problem.
But the second one is never fire. I've attached the event using API et declarative way. But nothing change.

Do you have already get the same issue ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logs around about the time it should get called?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use this tool to check wheather your event receivers are assigned correctly to the list where your content type is used:

http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2008/02/29/tool-eventreceiver-installer-for-sharepoint/

Maybe you have a configuration error in your feature definition.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Event Logs. Mine, most of the time, will place an error entry in the Application event log.